# How a for loop works without printing

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, for-loop, char

I've seen someone post this same for loop, but my problem is slightly different. Wouldn't the variable `temp` be changed on each iteration, so just leaving one character that keeps getting changed? How are the characters stored? Also, how does the loop know that `rand()` won't generate the same number for both `index1` and `index2`? Sorry if this isn't so clear, i'm a bit of a newbie!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
    enum { WORD, HINT, NUM_FIELDS };
    const int NUM_WORDS = 3;
    const std::string WORDS[NUM_WORDS][NUM_FIELDS] = {
        { "Redfield", "Main Resident Evil character" },
        { "Valentine", "Will you be mine?" },
        { "Jumbled", "These words are..." }
    };

    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));
    int choice = (rand() % NUM_WORDS);
    std::string theWord = WORDS[choice][WORD];
    std::string theHint = WORDS[choice][HINT];

    std::string jumble = theWord;
    int length = jumble.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        int index1 = (rand() % length);
        int index2 = (rand() % length);
        char temp = jumble[index1];
        jumble[index1] = jumble[index2];
        jumble[index2] = temp;
    }

    std::cout << jumble << '\n'; // Why 'jumbled word' instead of just a character?

    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Would the behaviour become more clear to you **with** printing?

Comment: If the two indices are the same, no change happens. So there does not really need to be a check. Did you run your debugger and go through your code step by step in order to try and understand its steps?

Comment: Good idea. I'll see if it makes things a bit more clear. Still not sure i'll understand why rand() doesn't duplicate characters from that though

Comment: The fact that rand could return the same value is a good reason to switch to a better algorithm like [Fisher Yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) .

Comment: All your code does is switching two characters `jumple.size()` times. `rand()` does not know if `index1` and `index2` are equal. If they are, the iteration simply has no effect. `jumble[2] = jumble[2]` does not modify the string.

Comment: @displayname I've read through it a stack of times, this is my understanding. temp is assigned the random character index1, index1 is then assigned the random character of index2 and then index2 is stored in temp. So temp is no longer index1, but index2? Still just confuses me :(

Comment: All this is doing is a *swap* of two characters within a string. Say you have `a=1` and `b=2`.. how do you swap? You store `tmp=a` then you assign `a=b` then you assign `b=tmp` - now `a` is 2 and `b` is 1. The only thing that's a bit different in your code is that you swap characters in an array, but that's about it.

Comment: @displayname so in the string 'jumble', all that is swapped is 2 characters? or does it swap 2 characters jumble.size() times?

Comment: It swaps two characters in each iteration (unless of course `index1` and `index2` happen two be equal). The number of iterations is `length` or `jumble.size()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Wouldn't the variable temp be changed on each iteration, so just leaving one character that keeps getting changed?

It depends. Notice that you're trying to come up with a new random `index1` and a new random `index2` in each iteration. What happens if your `jumble` variable is `Redfield`, and `index1 = 1` and `index2 = 5`? You would be swapping two `e`'s.

But because in every iteration you're trying to access `chars` in a random position of your `jumble` string on positions `index1` and `index2`:

```
int index1 = (rand() % length);
int index2 = (rand() % length);
```

The value of those indexes are unpredictable on each iteration. It could happen that you get a `1` and a `5` again.

Nevertheless, remember that you're creating a variable `temp`in every iteration, thereby you wouldn't be changing its value, you would be assigning a new variable in each iteration.

> How are the characters stored?

I'm not sure what do you mean here, but every char is stored within 1 byte. Therefore, a string would be a sequence of bytes (char). This sequence is a **contiguous** block of memory. Every time you're accessing `jumble[index1]`, you're accessing the char on position `index1` within your string `jumble`.

If `jumble = "Valentine"` and `index1 = 1`, then you will be accessing an `a`, because your `V` is on position 0.

> Also, how does the loop know that rand() won't generate the same number for both index1 and index2?

It doesn't. You would have to come up with a strategy to ensure that this doesn't happen. One approach, but not an efficient one, would be:

```
int index1 = (rand() % length);
int index2 = (rand() % length);
while (index1 == index2) {
    index1 = (rand() % length);
    index2 = (rand() % length);
}
```